# Substring between characters in Oracle 9i

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

In later versions I can use this `regexp_substr`:

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    regexp_substr(ID, '[^.]+', 1, 2) DATA 1, 
    regexp_substr(ID, '[^.]+', 1, 3) DATA 2 
FROM employees
```

Table:  **Employees**

```
ID
--------------------------
2017.1.3001-ABC.01.01
2017.2.3002-ABCD.02.02
2017.303.3003-ABC.03.03
2017.404.3004-ABCD.04.04
```

Expected output:

```
ID                       DATA 1 DATA 2
------------------------ ------ ---------
2017.1.3001-ABC.01.01    1      3001-ABC
2017.2.3002-ABCD.02.02   2      3002-ABCD
2017.303.3003-ABC.03.03  303    3003-ABC
2017.404.3004-ABCD.04.04 404    3004-ABCD
```

Please help me to get the sub-string between `.` characters in ID column in **SQL Oracle 9i**.

Comment: We cannot provide help if you dont ask a question?

Comment: wont there  be a column data3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions - just use `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`:

```
SELECT id,
       SUBSTR( id, dot1 + 1, dot2 - dot1 - 1) AS data1,
       SUBSTR( id, dot2 + 1, dot3 - dot2 - 1) AS data2
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         INSTR( id, '.', 1, 1 ) AS dot1,
         INSTR( id, '.', 1, 2 ) AS dot2,
         INSTR( id, '.', 1, 3 ) AS dot3
  FROM   employees
);
```

Comment: @joeharry - moreover, solutions using only INSTR and SUBSTR, as MT0 has demonstrated, should be used whenever possible even in later versions of Oracle, as they will very likely be significantly faster than anything using regular expressions.